# Generating my world map without visiting the region?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'd like my Minecraft map to get fleshed out a bit around the region where I'm at to see if there are villiages or other structures worth checking out. However I'd like to keep from walking around in circles just to get the game to generate the map. Is there a way I can get the game to generate a chunk of my map without having to get "close" to the chunk?

Comment: Not a perfect solution, but what I often do is switch to creative mode, fly around for a bit (it's faster than walking) to generate chunks, then switch back to survival mode to play. This also lets you get the lay of the land. Of course, this only works if you have cheats enabled.

Comment: Because the seed defines structure locations, you can actually determine these things *without* generating anything. Search for the AMIDST program on the minecraft forums—it works great for locating villages.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Ya that is in my answer... That i posted 15 days ago , and this is posted yesterday...

Comment: @SovietOnion Yeah! Sorry about that. I wrote it before I read the answers (oops) and upvoted yours. I'm on a phone so I can't delete comments. Feel free to flag it as obsolete. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of doing it in-game, try using a outside source. AMIDST is a program that lets you put in a certain seed or load an existing map and it generates the minecraft map as a picture. You can use it to see if there are dungeons, pyramids, ruins, villages, even strongholds!

***Edit***:
This way will also make you not download mods and keep you away from the want to spawn yourself items!

Comment: I think that program is called AMIDST.

Comment: @IncredulousMonk Ya just googled it, it's that.

Answer (score 3):

There is no other way to do it than in-game. One way you can optimize this is by getting [Optifine](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/249637-125-optifine-hd-c6-fps-boost-hd-textures-aa-af-and-much-more/), which will allow you to ramp up your render distance, making your client request chunks that are further away, speeding up the process.

Also consider using [SinglePlayerCommands](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/94310-125-single-player-commands-v322-official-download/)' `/fly` command with a high speed, e.g. `/fly 10` to fly around quickly to generate chunks. With a high enough speed, you'll be requesting chunks faster than your computer can generate them.

Answer (score 1):

World Edit comes with a world border tool. Once you set the borders, you can fill the world, generating all chunks inside the border, so you can simply look at the map and see.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. We try to avoid insulting people when we're asking or answering questions. As such, I am editing the question to make it more user friendly.

Comment: Also, I've read this right, wouldn't it all be filled with a certain block?